# Drawing a simple arch with the curve tool

Tags: bezier-curves

I think I'm losing my mind. I just want to draw a simple arch shape with the curve tool so that I can extrude it into a solid. I can add a bezier curve, I can move the points around, I can move the handles, I can add and remove points. But I can't figure out how to do anything else.

1. How do I make my drawing symmetrical?
2. How do I connect the end points of the bezier curve to create a closed shape?
3. How do I make sure that the curve has the correct measurements and proportions?

I just want to create something like the below but I cannot figure it out. I've spent hours searching how to do it and I just can't get it to work. I don't even really know how to describe my problem to search for it.

[image: Arch made in CAD.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go one by one:

1. Add the *Mirror Modifier*
2. Go *Curve > Toggle Cyclic*, shortcut: <kbd>Alt+C</kbd> (but it will mess with the mirror modifier)
3. Use *Orthographic view* and enable *Snapping to Increment* (with Absolute Grid snap)

*Add the Mirror modifier*

[image]

*Toggle cyclic curve*

[image]

*Set up Orthographic view (Front/Top/Side)*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful help, I've got the curve drawn! Now I need to figure out how to convert it into a mesh. Object -> Convert to -> Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text just creates a duplicate of the curve, though it has the inverted triangle "mesh" icon next to in the collection.

Comment: That's exactly what should happen :). Now you can hide the *bezier curve*, select the *mesh* and extrude it. If you get lost, feel free to ask a new question :). Good luck.