# Mirror modifier with Bezier Curve

Tags: mirror, bezier-curves

I am trying to mirror a bezier using the mirror modifier. I would like to then make the original and mirrored bezier join/merge as one continuous curve with one direction. I then want to continue adding to the last control point of the mirrored (joined) curve. 
Is this possible?

I have done the above in a different way, i.e not using the mirror modifier at all but duplicating the original Bezier, then flipping the duplicate, then joining, etc, but I wonder if I could do it more effectively using the mirror modifier.

Thanks.

[image: Mirror modifier, I'm stuck at this point]

Following from the above question, what I wanted to be able to do with the "mirror modifier" is shown in the sample below, i.e. just mirror parts of the curve, not all the curve.

I guess that for this purpose the quickest way is how I've done it, i.e. selecting the part of the curve that I want to mirror, in this sample, the top part, duplicate it, go to Curve--> Mirror and then Segments--> Switch direction, and then just continue adding to the end of the curve as normal.

[image]

Comment: Constructive modifies on curves only act on the "final mesh representation" of the curve, not on bezier points. What are you trying to solve? Which part of your workflow fails with the current *Mirror Modifier* solution?

Comment: Thank you, Duarte, I've elaborated above. But what prompted my asking is seeing this post:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170035/drawing-a-simple-arch-with-the-curve-tool        In the answer by Jachym, he creates a Mirror Modifier in the first picture. Then in the second picture he has a complete curve, with the directional arrows and control points on the mirrored half. I saw not way of emulating that without some intermediate steps, possibly similar to my post above. I just wanted to know, since I am learning, whether there is something I am missing.

Comment: No, as far as I know that isn't possible with curves at the moment. It was probably done manually as a separate step. If you notice in the gif there no longer is a *Mirror Modifier*. Default *Curve Tools* addon has some tools to help with this, like merging splines ends and removing doubles